# Discord Bot MySql query with concatenated int returns empty result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to check if a user's id exists in the table.
These two queries return their expected results:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM user_accounts', function (err, result, fields) {
```

and

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE discord_id=0000000000', function (err, result, fields) {
```

obviously with 0000000000 replaced with a manually entered id, but the line

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE discord_id=' + user.id + '', function (err, result, fields) {
```

returns empty?

Here's the entire function. Everything works aside from the query not returning what I expect.

```
function createAccount(msg, user) {
con.query('SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE discord_id=' + user.id + '', function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length == 0) {
        msg.reply(result.length);
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO user_accounts(discord_id, discord_name) VALUES(' + user.id + ', "' + user.username + '")';
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            msg.reply('Account created!');
        });
    } else {
        msg.reply('You already have an account!');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Seems your code's `user` is the same kind of object as your DB's `user_accounts`, right? If so, you want to match `user.discord_id`. In other words: if it works with a manually-inserted ID and doesn't work when using a variable, then the variable probably does not contain what you expect. Also, you might want to consider safely passing params: `con.query('SELECT ... WHERE discord_id = ?', [user.discord_id], function(err, res, fields) {...});`, or explicitly use `con.escape`.

Comment: I know what `user.id` contains because it shows up in my database when it's added, and it also is documented in the discord.js documentation. I tried parsing it as an int just to make sure it wasn't a type issue, but that didn't change anything either. Also yes, I was using `con.escape` but I took it out for now to help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE discord_id= '${user.id}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
```

Comment: That shows up as a parsing error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token $`

Comment: Are you sure that you used the ` quotes

Comment: Yes. I just typed it as you have here and it was caught as an error.